# How to use the Http response headers in successCriteria evaluation of the Invoke Rest Api Azure DevOps Pipelines deployment gates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am looking to use the [Invoke Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) deployment gates in my AzureDevOps pipeline.

But in the SuccessCriteria evaluation I want to parse the http response headers and compare a specific header value with a variable string. Is this supported or possible today?
[image]

Comment: Tried searching today for some info but I don't think this task stores the response header anywhere other than a basic Response Code: OK. All examples show how to check the response body. But keen to know if there's a way.